# Adobe air iOS application signing verification

Tags: ios, air, adobe, application-loader

I am having the following problem:

I compile my app in Adobe Flash CS6 and have no problem to upload, but if I uncompress the app with WINRAR, add localization.string files, compress it again and try to upload it, I get the error: `application failed codesigning verification`.

How to resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file _CodeSignature/CodeResoureces contains some kind of hash of all files. If you change some file its hash become different and the ipa file become invalid. You want to make some hacks and this is not posible for security reasons.